# Objective-C - How to Get Date Formatter to Add Colon in Time Zone Offset

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I'm trying to format a date to match the format expected on the server side.

- Wanted: 1985-01-24T00:00:00-07:00
- Got:       1985-01-24T00:00:00-0700
- Using:    yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ

Is there a date format trick I can use to get that colon in there?

Here is my code. _birthdate is the date supplied by the birthdate selector:

```
NSDate *birthdate = (NSDate *)resultObject;
[_birthdate setNewTitle:[IRDate mmddyyFromNSDate:birthdate]];            

//Set server-ready birthdate format
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
serverFormattedBirthDate = [formatter stringFromDate:birthdate];

NSLog(@"Birthdate: %@", serverFormattedBirthDate);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Date Format Specifiers](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) documentation, it looks like you'll need 5 `Z`'s.  That will get you things like `"-08:00"`.

---

Aha, I see what you're getting at.  If you run the formatting on OS X 10.8, you'll get the string you're expecting.  However, if you run the formatting on iOS 5.1, you'll get the extra "GMT" in the string.

I'm guessing that the underlying data has changed in recent versions of the CLDR.  In that case, I'm not sure what the correct answer is.

Comment: Yes but then that gives me 1985-01-24T00:00:00GMT-07:00. I don't want the GMT.

Comment: Running OS X 10.7.4 here. Couldn't get the exact string I wanted, but I have a workaround using five Z's like you suggest, then doing a string replace for "GMT" with "". This should work for the time being.